# Child class with method of covariant return type, workaround?

Tags: c#, inheritance, covariance

I'm trying to neatly organize my code and came across and oddity as primarily Java-focused programmer. Here's the simplified version:

```
class ReturnParent { ... }
class ReturnChild : ReturnParent { ... }

class Parent
{
    abstract ReturnParent SomeMethod();    
}

class Child : Parent
{
    // Note the return type
    override ReturnChild SomeMethod() {}
}
```

Now I've looked up this issue and I know this doesn't work in C# because covariance isn't supported in this way. My question is, is there a workaround to this issue?

The method can be a parameter instead; the classes, including the return classes, MUST be classes, they cannot be interfaces; they can implement interfaces though, if that helps.

Also, the main class must be castable, which was an issue when I tried generics:

```
    Parent p = new Child(); // This works
    Child c = p as Child; // This doesn't work with generics
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let the subclasses decide the return type of `SomeMethod`.

```
abstract class Parent<TReturn> where TReturn : ReturnParent
{
    public abstract TReturn SomeMethod();    
}

class Child : Parent<ReturnChild>
{
    public override ReturnChild SomeMethod(){}
}
```

If you make `Parent<T>` implement the following covariant interface, then you could cast `Child` to `IParent<ReturnParent>`.

```
interface IParent<out T>
{
    T SomeMethod(); 
}
```

If you want to make it castable *specifically* to `Parent<ReturnParent>`, then no, that can't be done, and you may need a redesign.

Comment: I've tried this, you can't cast this way. I tried writing a cast method myself, but couldn't manage a decent one.

Comment: @Marconius Why can't you? This seems fine to me: `Parent<ReturnChild> p = new Child(); Child c = p as Child;`

Comment: That works yes, but I want to be able to use `Parent<ReturnParent>`. For example, I want to be able to put a bunch of Parents in a list without knowing what the Return type is inside them, beyond the fact that they are all subclasses of ReturnParent.

Comment: @Marconius is `ReturnParent`/`ReturnChild` ever used as an argument for a method? Or as the type of a property with a setter?

Comment: There are multiple subclasses of ReturnParent (which is why I made a parent class for them in the first place). The ReturnChild method/parameter is basically read only, but it's a class with members and methods of its own.

Comment: @Marconius That's not what I meant.. I mean, do the `Child`/`Parent` classes have any method where `ReturnX` is used as an argument type, instead of a return type? Or are they *always* used as a return type?

Comment: Always a return type then, I suppose.

Comment: @Marconius Then you could make `Parent<T>` implement a covariant `IParent<out T>` interface. Ill update my answer.

Comment: Okay, so what I'd like to do doesn't seem to be possible. Thanks for your help. (I'm going to leave the question unanswered for a bit though, just in case someone else has a workaround of some sort.)

Answer (score 1):

This works with Linqpad

```
abstract class Parent<T>
{
    public abstract T SomeMethod();    
}

class Child : Parent<ReturnChild>
{
    // Note the return type
    public override ReturnChild SomeMethod()
    {
       return new ReturnChild();
    }
}

void Main()
{ 
    var p = new Child(); // This works
    Child c = p as Child; // This doesn't work with generics
}
```

Comment: yeah, he beat me to it :) His is slightly better i think as it has the constraint